# ffmpeg and python usage

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have an ffmpeg setup on my pc, which streams mp3 with this code:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Input device" -c:a libmp3lame -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.2:7777
```

Also i have a server and I want my python script to run 24/7 on server and start/stop writing stream to mp3 file every time pc get's turned on/off. I need new file every time pc turns on (use time and date for filename for example) to bypass overwriting. Using python's subprocess module and ffmpeg I can save file on my server like this:

```
subprocess.call('ffmpeg -y -i udp://192.168.1.2:7777 -acodec copy output.mp3')
```

But I need condition, when to start recording(listen if 7777 port is reciving data or something like that), is it even possible to implement such thing, using python?
P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem you are going to run into is that UDP is a connectionless protocol. In other words, it is difficult to determine when the "connection" no longer exists (the program sending the data has gone away).

If you switch to TCP, you should be able to write a Python script that runs your subprocess.call() in a loop giving it a new filename each time. Each time the PC shuts down and the TCP connection closes, the ffmpeg running on the server should (you'll need to test it to make sure) exit, and the loop will start a new one with a new output filename.